# Add a new role using the Drupal Services Rest api

Tags: services, users, 8

I'm trying to create a new role using the drupal services module. I am able to update a user with an already created role but can't find a way to add a new role. I'd rather not build a custom service for this so wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this without resorting to that.

Answer (score 0):

**First** of All you could create the custom resource in a custom module and enable it, for doing that follow that [tutorial](http://pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-drupal-7-restful-services)

**Second** in the callback function use that code to create a new role

```
$role = new stdClass();
$role->name = 'editor';
// $role->weight = 10;
user_role_save($role);
```

**Let** the role name be an argument taken from the request.